# Group Values Together in PHP / MySQL and Add the Value of one of the columns up into the group

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL Database That Looks like This:

```
Name: Joe
Items: 25
CreationDate: 2012-04-14 18:49:50

Name: John
Items: 89
CreationDate: 2012-04-14 18:47:17

Name: Bill
Items: 95
CreationDate: 2012-04-09 12:34:08

Name: Bob
Items: 35
CreationDate: 2012-04-09 12:18:23
```

What I want to do is group the rows by CreationDate (Based on only the day, the time at the end should not be a factor). And Then Add the Items Together to come up with an Items / Day.

So I want the output to be something like this:

```
2012-04-09 - 130 items
2012-04-14 - 114 items
```

I've tried the Group By in MySQL but I'm not sure if i'm using it right:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Items), CreationDate FROM People GROUP BY CreationDate ORDER BY CreationDate DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ) {
    echo '<p>' . $row['CreationDate'] . ' - ' . $row['SUM(Items)'] . '</p>';
}
```

That kind of works except it Groups them only on exact match Creation Date (Down to the second) and i'm not sure how to fix for that.

Comment: Just a little side-note, you might want to use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`. mysql_query is an old API. Read more about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the date-function for the CreationDate field, such as:

```
SELECT SUM(Items), DATE(CreationDate) FROM People GROUP BY DATE(CreationDate) ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

A warning though: Using the DATE-function will ignore any index on the CreationDate. If the CreationDate-field is indexed, using the DATE-function and grouping on it will take much longer time.

Comment: But How do I not take into consideration the Time At The End?

Comment: @Talon `DATE()` extracts only the date portion out of a datetime value.